# Placing a robots.txt file in an S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, robots.txt

I have static resources being served through an S3 bucket behind cloudfront. I'm trying to create a robots.txt file for this but the S3 bucket is showing up in a subdirectory (cdn.example.com/example rather than cdn.example.com). So I created a robots.txt file, but it's one directory up from the root.

How can I fix this? Is there a way to get Cloudfront to serve it from the root?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/DefaultRootObject.html is pretty much what you are looking for.

Comment: Yeah I found that, it does seem close but my understanding is that the default root object is for specifying termination of the root domain without a specific file in the path (e.g. index.html). I'm looking to return /example/robots.txt when /robots.txt is requested.

Comment: Simplest solution would be to create a 301 redirect at the DNS level for requests to /robots.txt to /example/robots.txt, but not sure if that would cause issues

Comment: oh gotcha, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/VirtualHosting.html#VirtualHostingCustomURLs using s3 cnames and then configuring cloudfront to honor them https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/MigrateS3ToCloudFront.html#adding-cloudfront-to-s3

Comment: or yeah what you said moving the file would just get it done